# Tkinter Listbox Positioning

Tags: tkinter

I am trying to move the listbox to sit in the middle of the window, and the listbox stays at the very top of the screen in the middle.

```
#centre listbox
lb = Listbox(my_window)

lb.insert(1, 'Fri, 13 Oct 2017')
lb.insert(2, 'Sat, 14 Oct 2017')
lb.insert(3, 'Sun, 15 Oct 2017')
lb.insert(4, 'Mon, 16 Oct 2017')
lb.insert(5, 'Tues, 17 Oct 2017')
lb.insert(6, 'Wed, 18 Oct 2017')
lb.insert(7, 'Thurs, 19 Oct 2017')
lb.insert(8, 'Latest')

lb.place(x=240, y=100)
lb.pack()
```

This is what I've put and the lb.place(...) values worked before and suddenly they aren't anymore, I am confused as to why I cannot move it.

Comment: There are probably half a dozen ways to place a widget in the middle of the window. The right choice depends on many factors, such as what other widgets are in the window, whether you want the widget to expand and contract, and so on. Can you be more specific, or do you literally just want a single listbox in the middle of a larger window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using two geometry managers on one object `.pack()` and `.place()` which is something that should **never** be done. `.place()` will take a set of coordinates and place the widget with it's top left corner at those coordinates. `.pack()` will place the widgets in the window stacked one after the other aligned to the top and middle.

`.place()` will do something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

button = Button(root, text="Placeholder")

button.place(x=0, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Which simply places the widget where desired.

`.pack()` however has a number of "intelligent" attributes which can be used to move the object around the screen.

By default `.pack()` will place the widget in the window like so:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

button = Button(root, text="Placeholder")

button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

But using some of these attributes we can manipulate it in all sorts of ways:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

button = Button(root, text="Placeholder")

button.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

As was pointed out by Bryan in the comments below, you can use relative x and y coordinates with `.place()` like below:

```
from tkinter import *

my_window = Tk()

lb = Listbox(my_window)

lb.insert(1, 'Fri, 13 Oct 2017')
lb.insert(2, 'Sat, 14 Oct 2017')
lb.insert(3, 'Sun, 15 Oct 2017')
lb.insert(4, 'Mon, 16 Oct 2017')
lb.insert(5, 'Tues, 17 Oct 2017')
lb.insert(6, 'Wed, 18 Oct 2017')
lb.insert(7, 'Thurs, 19 Oct 2017')
lb.insert(8, 'Latest')

lb.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor="center")
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked once I got rid of the .pack(). I didn't realised you couldn't put 2 in the same one

Comment: You should never use two geometry managers in the same window and therefore by extension, you should never use two geometry managers on one object

Comment: Note: if you want the widget in the middle of the window, and you want to use `place`, place lets you specify relative coordinates. I rarely choose `place`, but it is quite useful for very simple needs.

Comment: @EthanField: you _should_ use two geometry managers in the same _window_ -- they all have strengths and weaknesses, and you should use the right tool for the job.  You just can't use both `pack` and `place` on widgets that have the same parent or master. They can be in the same window, just not in the same parent.

Comment: @BryanOakley I've updated my answer to include relx and rely. And really? I was always under the impression that the use of two geometry managers in the same window was a cardinal sin and would more often than not cause tkinter to explode?

Comment: @EthanField: yes, really. `grid` and `pack` can both be used in the same window. The only time they can't be shared is when two or more widgets share the same parent. I don't know if I've ever created a GUI that didn't use both.

Comment: The more you know